# Display image from mysql in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display an image, whose path is stored in the DB. Although the file path is retrieved correctly the image is not displayed on the web page. This is the HTML snippet:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row["path"];
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
    error_log($row['path'], 0);
    error_log($row["path"], 0);
    ?>"/>
```

The output from above indicates that the file path is correct

*[17-Jul-2016 10:44:22] ./uploads/18-araya.jpg*

I initially tried the following  but it didn't work either

```
 <img src="<?=$row['path']?>"/>
```

Comment: You should use `echo` or `print`.

Comment: are you sure that your images stored in this path? yourdomain.com`.`/uploads/18-araya.jpg

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo The current directory ./ contains the index.php (where the above code is). The file is located at the indicated path ./uploads/18-araya.jpg. I also tried to use the path uploads/18-araya.jpg and it doesn't work either. It seems like this is a file access problem, but can't tell whats wrong

Comment: how about `/uploads/18-araya.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but didn't fix the problem. This is from the page source code     
    <div class="imgholder"><!-- image -->
       <img src="/uploads/18-araya.jpg"/>
  </div><!-- image hover -->

Answer (score 0):

simply use `<img src="<?php echo $row['path'];?>"/>`

If your image is not loaded, view the source code and check the src value.

Comment: Thanks, This change didn't fix the problem. Like you said I looked at the source code and it seems to be right <img src="./uploads/18-araya.jpg"/>. Maybe a file access problem but can't tell

Comment: I thinks the file path is wrong. 

Try like `"uploads/18-araya.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<img src="<?= $row['path'];?>"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `<img src="<?=$row['path']?>"/>`

To

`<img src="<?= echo $row['path']; ?>"/>`